# Defining variables in a class

Tags: c++, class

I am making a polynomial program, and below is the code I have written for it.

```
class Polynomial{
private:

int n;  //n = degree of polynomial
double a[n];            //a = array of coefficients where a[i] is the coefficient of x^i
double roots[n];
double maxima[n-1],minima[n-1],inflection[n-1]; //arrays of coordinates of maxima, minima and points of inflection
```

This is just a part of the class Polynomial in the header file. When I try compiling, it gives me the following error

```
invalid use of non-static data member  int n;
```

and when I make n static , it gives me the following error

```
 array bound is not an integer constant before ‘]’ token
```

This is on compiling the header file alone. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Your class contains VLA (variable lenghth arrays) which is not 
supported in C++.

You need to either determine the size by making `n` constant
or use another type of container that is dynamic, std::vector
is a container that resembles an array but is dynamic i.e. can
be expanded during runtime.

```
class Polynomial
{
  static const int n = 10;
  double a[n];
  ...

class Polynomial
{
  std::vector<double> a;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply allocate all these in a constructor using `new`.
**Or** use vectors.

```
class Polynomial
{
    vector<double> a;
    Polynomial()
    {
        a.assign(n,0);
        ...
    }
..
};
```

Comment: You can use `double *a` and allocate `a=new double[n]` or whatever in constructor or use vector as mentioned above.

Comment: @DhanviSreenivasan see my answer for complete details of using `new` as suggested by coderredoc

Answer (score 0):

The size of C-style arrays must be known at compile time.

If `n` is in fact known at compile-time, you could make it a template parameter instead of a member variable.

If not then you will have to use a different container, such as `vector<double> a, roots, maxima, minima, inflection;` .

Answer (score 0):

Without getting into complications,

the simple answer is that for **static memory allocation** to work (which is what you are trying to do with `double a[n];`) you need to know the size of the array at compile time.

However, if you do not know the size of the array even before the program runs, but instead, expect to know it somewhere during the runtime of the program, then you need to use **dynamic memory allocation**.

To do this you will have to

- Declare **pointers** instead of static arrays.

and

- Assign them memory using the `new` directive

and then later

- When you don't need them, for instance when the scope of the class ends, you will have to free the memory you allocated using the `delete` directive with `[]` parenthesis to indicate the compiler to free memory for more than one consecutive variable.

Do something like:

```
class Polynomial{
private:
int n; //n = degree of polynomial
double *a; //a = array of coefficients where a[i] is the coefficient of x^i
double *roots;
double *maxima,*minima,*inflection; //arrays of coordinates of maxima, minima and points of inflection
public:
 Polynomial( int degree_of_polynomial ){
     n = degree_of_polynomial;
     a = new double[n];
     roots = new double[n]; 
     maxima = new double[n-1];
     minima = new double[n-1];
     inflection = new double[n-1];

     ~Polynomial(){
        delete []a;
        delete []roots;
        delete []maxima;
        delete []minima;
        delete []inflection;
    }
 }
```

For a more detailed explanation of **dynamic memory allocation** see this [link](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/dynamic/).